# How can i insert text in javascript slideshow?

Tags: javascript, html, slideshow

Well...i am making a webpage (a pretend e-shop),and i want to put a slideshow with some text beneath each picture..so far i made the code for the picture slideshow

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
<title>Slide Show</title>
<style type="text/css">
body {
text-align: center;
margin: 0;
padding: 0;
}

#imageContainer {
<img id="imgreal" src="pics\bg.jpg" />

min-height: 550px;
document.getElementByID("imgreal").style.backgroundImage = string;

}

a  {
text-decoration: none;
padding: 5px;
color: #cccc00;
}
</style>

<script type="text/javascript">

var imgSlide;
var pic = 0;
window.onload = function ()
{

imgSlide = document.getElementById('img');

// preload images
images = new Array();
images[0] = new Image();
images[0].src = "images/img1.jpg" ;
images[1] = new Image();
images[1].src = "images/img2.jpg";
images[2] = new Image();
images[2].src = "images/img3.jpg";
images[3] = new Image();
images[3].src = "images/img4.jpg";
images[4] = new Image();
images[4].src = "images/img5.jpg";
images[5] = new Image();
images[5].src = "images/img6.jpg";


}

function slide()
{
imgSlide.src = images[pic].src;
if(pic < images.length-1) // images.length - 1 can be used here
{
pic++;
}
else
{
pic = 0

}
}

function prev()
{


if(pic == 0)
{

pic = 3;

imgSlide.src = images[pic].src;
}
else
{
pic--;
imgSlide.src = images[pic].src;
}
}

function next()
{


if(pic == images.length)
{

pic = 0;
imgSlide.src = images[pic].src;
}
else
{
pic++;
imgSlide.src = images[pic].src;
}


}




</script>




<DIV ID="SLIDESTEXT">&nbsp;</DIV>
</head>

<body background="pics\bg.jpg">

<div id="imageContainer"><img id="img" src="images/img1.jpg" alt="image" title="image"/></div>
<a href="JavaScript:prev()" title="Previous">Previous</a>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<a href="JavaScript:next()" title="Next">Next</a>

</body>
</html>
```

but i can not insert text to slide along with each picture...I'd appreciate some help very much

Comment: I'd suggest you to look at scripts for slide show in the Internet. There are plenty of them: with different libraries and in pure JS, light and huge, for images only and with multimedia support. Usually it doesn't worth to reinvent the wheel. But, if it does, you can always look at the code of any slide show you like.

Comment: Ryanpcmcquen has given you a simple working solution below.  And this library might give you some ideas on building your own slide show: [TemporizedSlider](http://lukelex.github.io/TemporizedSlider.js/) "A micro js that implements a temporized image slider, with custom text and title. "

Answer (score 1):

```
<div id="imageContainer"><img id="img" src="images/img1.jpg" alt="image" title="image"/></div>
<div><caption>hello</caption></div>
```

Just put another div under the images, using some kind of tag. You could assign values to it within the JS.